# How does client side validation know that ID is required without DataAnnotation attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partal view for my create and edit views.

In that partial is a: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)`

In my POCO that property is not decorated with the [Required] attribute but when I go to the create page and click save the client side validation kicks in and says ID is required.

Why does it think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers are required by default unless you define it as int? (nullable int)

Answer (score 0):

Value types are implicitly validated by the MVC framework.

To turn this off set DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes to false in global.asax